# No puedo enviar datos aun archivo PHP con AJAX

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Necesito ayuda con un problema, tengo un archivo PHP, en el cual dentro hay un script que se encarga de enviar los datos de un formulario a otro PHP el cual luego lo subirá a la base de datos, pero no puedo enviar los datos a dicho archivo, probé ponerle un alert con el error y me salió [object Object], pero en la consola no me sale nada, todo el programa viene de un tutorial y lo he hecho tal y como pone, pero nada

```
//Eventos de Botones de la aplicacion
         $('#BotonAgregar').click(function () {
        let registro = recuperarDatosFormulario();
        console.log(registro);
        agregarRegistro(registro);
        $('#FormularioEventos').modal('hide');
    });

        //duncion para cominicarse con AJAX
        function agregarRegistro(registro){
            $.ajax({
                data: registro,
                type: 'POST',
                url: '../controllers/datoseventos.php?accion=agregar',
                success: function (msg) {
                    calendar.fetchEvents();
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    console.log(registro);
                    alert("Hubo un error al agregar el evento: "+ error);
                }
            })
        }

        //funciones de interaccion con el formulario
        function limpiarFormulario() {
            $('#Id').val('');
            $('#Titulo').val('');
            $('#Descripcion').val('');
            $('#FechaInicio').val('');
            $('#FechaFin').val('');
            $('#HoraInicio').val('');
            $('#HoraFin').val('');
            $('#ColorFondo').val('#3788D8');
            $('#ColorTexto').val('#FFFFFF');
        }

        function recuperarDatosFormulario(){
            let registro = {
                id: $('#Id').val(),
                titulo: $('#Titulo').val(),
                descripcion: $('#Descripcion').val(),
                inicio: $('#FechaInicio').val()+ ' '+ $('#HoraInicio').val(),
                fin: $('#FechaFin').val()+ ' '+ $('#HoraFin').val(),
                colorBackground: $('#ColorFondo').val(),
                colortext: $('#ColorTexto').val()
            }
            console.log(registro)
            return registro;
        }
```

Aquí esta el bloque de código en el hago el enlace de datos, y en este tengo tengo como se tratan los datos

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');

require ('conexion.php');


switch ($_GET['accion']){
    case 'listar':
        $consulta = "SELECT id, titulo as title, descripcion,inicio as start, fin as end,colorText,colorBackground, participante from eventos";
        $datos = mysqli_query($CRM, $consulta);
        $resultado = mysqli_fetch_all($datos, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        echo json_encode($resultado);
        break;

        //funcion Agregar
    case 'agregar':
        $consulta = "INSERT into eventos(titulo, descripcion, inicio, fin, colorText,colorBackground) values ('$_POST[titulo]','$_POST[descripcion], '$_POST[inicio]', '$_POST[fin]', '$_POST[colorText]', '$_POST[colorBackground]', '$_POST[participante]')";
        $respuesta = mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta);
        echo json_encode($respuesta);
        break;
        
    case 'modificar':
        $consulta = "UPDATE eventos set titulo='$_POST[titulo]', descripcion = '$_POST[descripcion]', inicio = '$_POST[inicio]', fin = '$_POST[fin]', colorText='$_POST[colortText]', colorBackground='$_POST[colorBackground]', participante= '$_POST[participantes]' WHERE id = $_POST[id]";
        break;
    case 'borrar':
        $consulta = "DELETE from eventos where id = $_POST[id]";
        break;
}
?>
```

El problema creo que esta en el Ajax

Comment: Hola Sebas, dos cosas: 1. `[object Object]` te aparece porque `error` es un objeto, si queres podes convertirlo a JSON usando `JSON.stringify(error)`. 2. En el `INSERT` te falta agregar el campo `participante` y por eso falla la consulta. Saludos! PD: Deberías considerar utilizar sentencias preparadas.

Comment: Muchas gracias @Marcos, no era solo el que le faltaba al **INSERT** si no que uno de los campos le faltaba una de las comillas lo cual me daba un error , gracias al **JSON.stringify(error)** pude verlo